# Rails: create a relationship between comment and user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to connect the create of a comment to the `current_user`. I have a model `comment` which is a polymorphic association.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller I'm trying to connect the `@comment.user = current_user`.
controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: 'Comment Was Created'
  end
```

But I get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `user=' for #
>   Did you mean?  user_id=

I would rather set up a relationship from which I can get to a user (The creator of comment) from the comment itself. For example `@comment.user` instead of just having the id.

I have the following models:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_rich_text :content
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :questions
  has_one_attached :avatar

  before_create :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.avatar = 'assets/images/astronaut.svg' if self.new_record?
  end
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Since `comment` is a polymorphic association, I'm not sure if it should be connected to user via a `belongs_to` to `user`.

```
[5] pry(#<Questions::CommentsController>)> @comment
=> #<Comment:0x00007fb3e6df72e8
 id: nil,
 content: "some test content",
 commentable_type: "Question",
 commentable_id: 1,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 user_id: nil>
[6] pry(#<Questions::CommentsController>)>
```

Does this mean, I should create a foreign_key in the `comments` migration to a user? How can I go about getting the creator of the comment from the comment itself? Something like `@comment.creator` or `@comment.user`?

Comment: you can use `@comment.user_id = current_user`  and error will go away.

Comment: How is your commentable model?? Also i dont see any has_many..belongs_to between comment and user model also. Adding `belongs_to :user` in comment model may solve.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar `@comment.user_id = current_user` gives me `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint` `current_user.id` would work but I want to get the user from the comment not just get the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `user` model add

```
has_many :comments
```

and in your `comment` model add

```
belongs_to :user
```

then you can do

```
@comment.user
@user.comments
```

but if you only want to get the `user` from `comments` and never the other way round then you can only add `belongs_to :user` in `comment`.